# reCaptcha v3: should I post to Google's verification API even if I have no token?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I'm currently implementing Google's reCAPTCHA v3 to guard a form. Normally, the way this works is that when a user submits the form, a user response token is generated and conveyed to the back end, which then forwards the token to Google's verification API to get an assessment.

I've found that, for certain attacks, the user response token is missing because the attacker is submitting their POST request to my site directly, rather than using the form. This is good because it makes it obvious that they should be rejected. But I'm wondering if I should go ahead and submit a token-less verification request to Google anyway, knowing that it will fail.

I ask because my understanding is that reCAPTCHA gathers information about my site activity over time, using it to fine tune their assessments. I don't know how this is done, so I don't know if it would be useful to exercise the verification API even when I already know what should be the outcome.

Comment: Personally I'd recommend against this. I find it highly unlikely that Google would record and take into consideration requests that fail validation.